# QMessageBox - Style sheet for it

Tags: qt

I am using *QMessageBox* and trying to use `setSyleSheet` to change the background colours.

In the picture you see, the top half has white background and the bottom half has a grey background.

I wish to change these colours. I have been unsuccessful and have not found any useful pointers on the web. What is the correct CSS to do this?

[image: Dialog box]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMessageBox>

int  main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication  a(argc, argv);
    // Create a QMessageBox
    QMessageBox  msgBox;

    // Set the text and title
    msgBox.setText("This is a QMessageBox");
    msgBox.setWindowTitle("Customized QMessageBox");

    // Set the background color of the QMessageBox
    msgBox.setStyleSheet("background-color: lightblue;");

    // Customize the text color
    QColor  textColor(255, 0, 0);     // Red text color

    msgBox.setStyleSheet(QString("background-color: lightblue; color: %1;").arg(textColor.name()));

    // Get the palette of the QMessageBox to modify child widget colors
    QPalette  palette = msgBox.palette();

    // Set the background color of child widgets (QLabel)
    palette.setColor(QPalette::Window, QColor(255, 255, 0));      // Yellow background color
    msgBox.setPalette(palette);

    // Show the QMessageBox
    msgBox.exec();

    return a.exec();
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But I do not want the whole background the same colour. In the example in the question the box is divided. Top bit is white with the label. Bottom bit is grey with the button. How can I change those two bits.

Comment: @EdHeal when you set a nameless style, it us set to particular element. In vase things like QMessageBix implementation may vary and may contain other widgets. You have to set style for whole QWidget class (see QSS and CSS selectors)

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie How does one find out the widgets in the box?

Comment: @EdHeal: `children()` but you don't need to. As I said, read about QSS. You're explicitly giving style that doesn't affect widget's children.

Comment: @EdHeal if you want to set stylesheet for just one specific object you need to add "#objectname".for example `QPushButton#pushButtonName
{
 background-color: rgb(51, 209, 122);
}`